# In pip install libretranslate , Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [58 lines of output]
(running 'icu-config --version')
(running 'pkg-config --modversion icu-i18n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 63, in 
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\os.py", line 679, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'ICU_VERSION'

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 66, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 19, in check_output
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 69, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 19, in check_output
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling subprocess with ``shell=True`

like this;

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=tmpfile, shell=True)
```